# Get parameters from URL with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this type of URL:

```
https://example.com/page#param1|param2
```

How can I get `param1` and `param2` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those are part of the hash if you are getting them from the current url.

```
_hash = window.location.hash.split("|")
console.log(_hash)
```

Comment: Can we make this in PHP too ?

Comment: @Gepeto, no. Server side can process queries (`?param=1`), but not hash values, as their change on the browser doesn't trigger a new request to the server.